# Pass data from single activity to start destination fragment using Architecture Component Navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I've got the following `Activity`, which is the single one in my app:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        PermissionState state = PermissionState.get(this);
        if (state == PermissionState.GRANTED) {
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(-1));
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding mainActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(mainActivityBinding.toolbarMain);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mainActivityBinding.toolbarMain, Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment));
    }
}
```

The layout associated with the `Activity` is the following and was created following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#add_a_navhostfragment_using_the_layout_editor) Android Developers tutorial.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

The [navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Connect-destinations) is the following:

**nav_graph.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings" />
</navigation>
```

Now, other than the hosting `Activity`, my app has two `Fragment`s, one is the main, the other is for settings.
The main `Fragment` is the start destination of my app, and there I would like to retrieve the **MainActivity** variable "PermissionState state" to perform some actions based on the state of the permissions, like hiding or showing some `View`s.

Using Android Architecture Component Navigation API version `1.0.0-beta01` onwards, what is the correct, nondeprecated strategy to pass data from the hosting `Activity` to the start destination `Fragment`, maybe using [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) if possible?

Comment: It helps me as well (like)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Find a solution,works fine but i don't like it there's must be a better solution for that.

In your Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_controller_fragment)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("name","your value")
    navController.setGraph(navController.graph,bundle)
}
```

In your start Fragment:

```
  val args: MainFragmentArgs by navArgs()
  textView.text = args.name
```

In your navGraph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
          android:name="com.haidar.mediasaver.fragments.MainFragment"
          android:label="main_fragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
    <argument android:name="name"
              app:argType="string"/>
</fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Why don't you like this solution? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: There is no drawback. I just don't want to set graph twice. I find a method navController.getGraph.add arguments() and I think that's maybe the better way. But I didn't know much about this method working.

Comment: Why `Bundle` instead of SafeArgs?

Comment: With last version of Navigation component, use MainFragmentArgs.Builder to create start fragment bundle.

Comment: ^ @A.Ferrand How?

Comment: is there any way I can save that arg, so that when I switch bottom nav tabs it is not null, I actually have bottom navigation set using navigation component, when I pass data from activity to first fragment of bottom nav it works, but when I switch my bottom navigation tabs it comes as null.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) makes start destination to be created with default arguments.  When you call navController.setGraph(navController.graph,bundle) start destination is called again with real argument values. So problem is that default destination fragment will be called two times. I haven't found example code to prevent this behavior. Google does not provide working example in official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start

Answer (score 23):

If you use safe args, you need to do:

1. Remove the `app:navGraph` attribute from your `NavHostFragment`
2. Then call:

   ```
   findNavController(R.id.nav_controller_fragment)
                    .setGraph(
                         R.navigation.nav_graph,
                         MainFragmentArgs("your values").toBundle()
   )
   ```

Comment: Perfect way to do so! Do it once, do it wisely!